# Given is a sequence $a_n$. $a_1=7$ and $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n^2+3}{2(a_n-1)}$. Prove that $a_n>a_{n+1}>3$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given is a sequence $a_n$. $a_1=7$ and $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n^2+3}{2(a_n-1)}$ $n\in \Bbb N$. Prove that $a_n>a_{n+1}>3$ for all $n\geq 1$.

So I've proven that $a_n$ and$a_{n+1}$ are bigger than $3$ for all $n\geq 1$ by induction, but I'm stuck at proving that $a_n>a_{n+1}$.

Also, since this sequence is bounded below and monotone decreasing, I know it converges. But I can't just say that it converges to $3$ now, can I?

Comment: To answer the last question, no. Because you also have $a_n\gt 2\gt1.4\gt-1...$

Comment: @Shuri2060 But I can say it's convergent right?

Comment: Not necessarily - depends on your reasoning. If you're just going by $(\forall n)\,\,\,a_n>3$ then you could have as your sequence $5,4,5,4,...$. However, if you're using $(\forall n)\,\,\,a_n>a_{n+1}>3$, then yes.

Comment: @Shuri2060 But we also know it decreases, since $a_n>a_{n+1}$

Comment: The justification there is that the sequence is decreasing and bounded below. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem

Comment: Why wouldn't $a_n \cdot a_1 = 7$ imply that $a_n$ is a constant sequence?

Comment: @user193319 It's a full stop after $a_n$. So We only know $a_1=7$

Comment: I have found the limit $a_n\to\dfrac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{13}\right)$

Comment: @Raffaele But that's not possible since $a_n>3$ for every $n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we have $$a_n-a_{n+1}=a_n-\frac{a_n^2+3}{2(a_n-1)}=\frac{2a_n^2-2a_n-a_n^2-3}{2(a_n-1)}=\frac{(a_n+1)(a_n-3)}{2(a_n-1)}>0$$ since $$a_n>3$$

Comment: Why does $a_n>3$?

Comment: he has wrote that it was proven that $$a_n>a_{n+1}>3$$

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have prooved that
$$a_n>3$$ for every $n=1,2,\dots$
we have, 
$$a_n>a_{n+1}\Leftrightarrow a_n>\frac{a_n^2+3}{2(a_n-1)}\overset{a_n-1>0}{\Leftrightarrow}2a_n(a_n-1)>a_n^2+3\Leftrightarrow a_n^2-2a_n-3>0$$
Now, let us consider the polynomial:
$$p(x)=x^2-2x-3$$
We have:
$$\Delta=(-2)^2-4(-3)=16=4^2$$
so, its roots are:
$$x_{1,2}\frac{2\pm4}{2}=-1\mbox{ or }3$$
Since the leading coefficient is positive, we have that:
$$p(x)>0\mbox{ for every }x>3$$
So, since $a_n>3$, we have that:
$$p(a_n)>0\Leftrightarrow a_n^2-2a_n-3>0$$
which is equivalent to the wanted inequality.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_{n+1}-3=\frac{a_n^2+3}{2(a_n-1)}-3=\frac{(a_n-3)^2}{2(a_n-1)}$$
and since $a_1>3$ by induction we obtain $a_n>3$ for all $n$.

In another hand,
$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{a_n^2+3}{2(a_n-1)}-a_n=\frac{(3-a_n)(a_n+1)}{2(a_n-1)}<0,$$
which says $a_n>a_{n+1}>3$ and we are done!